# Spark structured streaming and data in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, streaming, spark-streaming

We are developing a streaming application using Kafka, Spark Structured Streaming, Hive and s3.

My manager says use s3 instread of Hive. 
But my question/concern is s3 sits on the AWS cloud which is on the network.

My application data flows from Kafka to spark layer to running business logic.

The intermediate data we are suppose to write and read from Hive.

If I place this on s3, what kind of problems will I need to address or encounter?

1. How to deal with latency?
2. Is there any industry standard best practices I need to follow?

Plz share more details or links if you come across ...

Comment: Slow is the go here